# Add optional special characters in the regex

Tags: regex

I want to add special characters on optional input in regex. currently i am using this for alphanumeric pattern.

```
 (?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20})$
```

I am using this

```
 (?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\\-`.+,\]{8,20})$
```

for adding special characters but now it gets optional for numeric numbers also, but i want to have a condition of at least one numeric number. Can anyone help me out to set this ?

Comment: Please give examples of strings you do and don't want the regex to match. :)

Comment: aaaaaaa1, aaaaaaa1@, for me special characters should be optional but atleast one number should be compulsory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another lookahead assertion for number presence:

```
^(?![0-9]+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[-a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\\`.+,]{8,20}$
```

Loolahead `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` will assert presence of at least one digit in input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VIqfe3/1)

Comment: Maybe should also assert the presence of at least one letter to avoid passwords like `############0`

Comment: yep i want this condition compulsory too

Comment: can you add at least one letter presence also in  the suggested regex !

Comment: ^(?![0-9]+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[-a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\\`.+,]{8,20}$

Comment: Hey, can you verify this regex ? is it working fine for all special characters including underscore and also alphanumeric   ^(?![0-9]+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=(.*\d){1,})[-a-zA-Z0-9_(.*\W)]{8,20}$

Comment: firstly it should not work for whitespaces, secondly i want want this regex to work for alphanumeric(at least one number and one letter, limit of 8 to 20, all special characters are optional). The strings it should'nt work would be aaaaaaa!, 1111111!. The valid could be aaaaaaa1! or 1111111a!

Comment: Regex already doesn't allow any whitespace and rest of requirements were addressed more than 3 years ago. If you got new requirements then please open a new question. However if it is not meeting any existing requirements then please edit your question and add example strings.